# Creating a remember me function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have a disclaimer tick box on my login page and i want to make it so when its clicked it remains clicked the next time a person visits the site.

The site is javascript/jquery php based and onchange of the tick box is then written and stored in a database and can thus be retrieved, but i need to associate a user to this isclicked database value now.

So i need like a browser id, or i need to set a cookie or something, can anyone advise me as to the best way top go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common and more basic way to do this is to write a cookie with the username and another with the hashed password. But i think you should write the cookies with PHP, JS is a client-side language so you can't hide your salt, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

> So i need like a browser id, or i need to set a cookie or something, can anyone advise me as to the best way top go about this?

as there is no [unique] browser id nor "something" you have to stick with cookie.

Comment: Why have to? Cookies are not ideal for you cant share them between multiple devices.

Comment: I am afraid you didn't get the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies in PHP, call the PHP script using jQuery.

jQuery:

```
$("#tick-me").live("click", function(){
    $.get("remember.php", function(data) {
        if ( data == 'OK' ){
             // Success, do something...
        } else {
             // Failure, do something...
        }
    });
});
```

Then in remember.php:

```
<?php
setcookie( 'remember_me', true, time()+(3600*24*7) ); // Remember for 7 days
echo 'OK';
```

In your HTML form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if ( isset($_COOKIE['remember_me']) ) echo 'checked="checked"; ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a cookie [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cookie to store values between the sessions however if you are saying that you have a database that stores the state of the check box, then I suppose all you need is to store some identification to know to whom the record belongs.

- If your user's login then it's easy because you use their userid with your check box status
- If the do not login then its more complicated:

  - you can store a cookie with user id on the user's computer (what is users use different computers?)
  - you can recognize users by their IP (flawed in a sense that there may be many users behind same IP via NAT
  - Make them login :)

I suppose it's up to you if you want to use the database + cookies or store all information in cookies or store all information in the database. Bear in mind that only true way to really discern between users is to make them login as nowadays people have more that one web access points (home, work, iPad itp) which will not have their settings if you use cookies or IP address to discern them.

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve through cookie...

```
setcookie( 'remember_me', true);
```

next time when user open site then cookie will be set .. you can put condition to make checkbox selected accordingly by applying if condition on $_COOKIE['remember_me'].